# Disabling PhpStorm database tool query caching for MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, caching, phpstorm

For all of my connections I'd like to disable the query caching feature when I use either the console or table view within PhpStorm.

There are an enormous amount of "Advanced" settings for each connection I have, but it's unclear which key/value pair I should modify to completely disable the default caching.